# How to refer to to a SQLite database from an 'independent' Method in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have code to access a SQLite table that works perfectly from my "main" activity. I'm trying to make the code more elegant by creating a separate class to handle data inserts, deletes, etc.

When I move the exact same code from the main activity to a separate class I get the following error:

> The method
>   openOrCreateDatabase(String, int,
>   null) is undefined for the type
>   BarCode

I notice that by extending my database class with "Activity" the error goes away. However, now I am getting **NullPointerException** when I run the code.

How would be the correct way to abstract database code and still be able to refer to it from an activity in Android?

Excuse me if I am getting the jargon wrong because I am a newbie to Android and Java.

Here is the full code:

```
package com.example.stockcontrol;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class BarCode extends Activity {

 public BarCode() {

 }

 public void insertBarCode(String upc) {

  SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = openOrCreateDatabase(
         "StockControl.db"
         , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY
         , null
        );
        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);

        ContentValues mUpc = new ContentValues();
        mUpc.put("upc", "444");
        mUpc.put("description", "Box o toast");
        mUpc.put("scan_count", "1");
        db.insertOrThrow("tbl_upc", null, mUpc);

 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having your database class extend Activity, you should pass the relevant Context to the class.  You can pass it in the constructor and keep a reference to the Context as a class variable.

```
public class BarCode {
    private final Context mContext;

    public BarCode(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void insertBarCode(String upc) {

     SQLiteDatabase db;
           db = mContext.openOrCreateDatabase(
            "StockControl.db"
            , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY
            , null
           );
           db.setVersion(1);
           db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
           db.setLockingEnabled(true);

           ContentValues mUpc = new ContentValues();
           mUpc.put("upc", "444");
           mUpc.put("description", "Box o toast");
           mUpc.put("scan_count", "1");
           db.insertOrThrow("tbl_upc", null, mUpc);

    }
}
```

To use the class, you would do this in your Activity:

```
BarCode barCode = new BarCode(this);
barCode.insertBarCode("123456");
```

Comment: Also , the `openOrCreateDatabase and setXXXX` part would be better in a `open` method . If he wants to insert several rows, he wont need to go through the `openOrCreateDatabase` process every time

Comment: You guys rock! Would you say this is a good method for achieving what I want to do or should I still stick with a data helper?

Comment: @Eugene: See  http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/Context.html#openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the way to go about these things is to create a data helper. I followed this tutorial and now I can reference the database code from anywhere:
http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742

Edit:
I found a much better tutorial, in fact, an excellent one from Google themselves that contains a number of best practices for doing this kind of thing including using a data adaptor to properly abstract database access. This is the Notebook Tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the DB pointer to your mUpc routine.

```
mUpc.put(db,"upc","444");
```

You will have to rewrite the constructor of mUpc to accept the db object.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I will give that a shot as soon as I understand how to write a constructor to accept an object. In the meanwhile I have discovered the Notepad tutorial for Android here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

I think I still have a lot to learn!